# why Relay low and high inversely?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, relay

I have a very strange relay problem. I wrote a code to change LED state in RaspberryPi. before I purchased the 4-channel 5v relay board I used LED to indicate HIGH and LOW. That works perfectly fine, but once I connect the relay board it switch vigorously for about half a second, and then work inversely to the outputs, the outputs are generally low but the relays then stay at the normally open positions and switch over to normally closed once they get a high.
To make this more confusing, I connected the relays together with the LED's just to be sure, now the LED's still light up correctly and the relays still switch incorrectly
What bugs me though?

```
from gpiozero import LED
from time import sleep

red = LED(17)

while True:
    red.on()
    sleep(1)
    red.off()
    sleep(1)
```

[image]

Comment: This most likely is not a bug in software. Any relay has 3 interfaces, #1 for input power, #2 for output high when signal is high, #3 for output high when signal is low. So you can connect the relay in any way you want. Some devices need always on but cutoff when signal is high, or the other way. Just change the connection to the other one to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

(1) Ah, your relay module has a JD-Vcc jumper, so you need to cap/uncap the jumper and wire the Rpi 3V3 signal line and 3V3 or 5V power lines accordingly.

The JD-Vcc jumper setting is a a bit complicated.

You might like to read the following EE SE Q&A for more details on wiring the signal and power lines for JD-Vcc relay module:

[How to properly use a relay module with a JD-VCC jumper for Raspberry Pi?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/505318/how-to-properly-use-a-relay-module-with-jd-vcc-from-arduino-raspberry)

---

(2) Your "***Status LED shows on but relay not switched on/off accordingly***" might be related the common problem of "***Relay always on but never off***" or "***Rpi's logical High signal is not High enough to switch off relay***".

The reason is that Rpi High is only about 3V but not high enough as Arduino High which is specified as 4V.  So the status LED misleadingly shows On status but relay not switched Off/On accordingly.  (This confusing problem arises because the relay is originally designed for Arduino whose logical High is higher than Rpi High.)

Again this is complicated to explain by a couple of sentences．You might like to read the above EE SE Q&A (***Especially Appendix B***) for more details.